# Swap area for ubuntu installation

Tags: partitioning, swap

I have 4 GB RAM on my laptop, and i allocated 3 GB for swap area while installing.So is having that much swap area harmful for my laptop? And if yes, then how can i change the size of swap area.How much swap area should i have allocated?  When i run command

```
swapon --show
```

It shows

```
NAME      TYPE SIZE USED PRIO
/swapfile file   2G  59M   -2
```

But here, it shows only 2 GB, .So Does that mean swapfile and swapspace different? I don't know what to do. I am new to Ubuntu. Please help.

Comment: 4GB swap for 4GB RAM is normal if you want to hibernate.

Comment: It is possible that there is a 2GB swapfile plus a 3GB swap partition on your HDD and that the swap partition has been turned off. Open Disks and check if you see a swap partition.

Comment: I don't see any swap partition on my Disks.Does that mean swap partition has been turned off automatically? Does the size of swap partition affect the laptop hardware?And one more question, if i don't want to enable hibernation, then my current swap file size is good , i don't need to change it, right? I am new to these things, Please forgive me for dumb questions, if any.

Comment: You have a swap file, not a swap partition. Size of swap file should not affect hardware. Size should be good, you can occasionally run `free` to check that swap is not all used up.

Answer (score 1):

### To Enlarge Swap Space:

```
sudo swapoff -a
```

- Delete your existing swap file located at root
- Create the new swap file:

  `sudo fallocate -l XG /swapfile`

Where X is the swapfile size in GB (4GB in your case)

```
sudo mkswap /swapfile

sudo chmod 0600 /swapfile

sudo swapon /swapfile
```

- Reboot:

  `sudo reboot`

**To enable Hibernation (optional):**

- Edit /etc/default/grub to add resume location and offset to grub.cfg:

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash resume=UUID=XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX resume_offset=XXXXX"`

- Use UUID from root.
- Use offset from `sudo filefrag -v /swapfile`

`cscameron@cscameron-T:~$ filefrag -v /swapfile Filesystem type is: ef53 File size of /swapfile is 4819255296 (1176576 blocks of 4096 bytes) ext:     logical_offset:        physical_offset: length:   expected: flags: 0:        0..       0:     303104..    303104:      1: 1:        1..    2047:     303105..    305151:   2047:             unwritten 2:     2048..    4095:     311296..    313343:   2048:     305152: unwritten`

- resume_offset=303104
- Update GRUB

  `sudo update-grub`
- Test hibernation

  `sudo systemctl hibernate`
- There is a slight possibility of getting holes in a swapfile when creating it with fallocate. /var/log/syslog can be searched for `swapon: swapfile has holes` to ensure there will be no data loss.

**A hibernate button can be added using gnome extensions.**

### Proof of concept that hibernation works with a swapfile

[image]
Showing swapfile, resume and UUID's
[image]
Showing hibernation popup
[image]
Showing resume from UUID is root partition and not from swap partition

Comment: `fallocate ` is not recommended to create swap files. `dd` is the suggested tool. See `man swapon` for details. See my answer.

Comment: @heynnema Actually fallocate is recommended quite often, it is the first method recommended by Google. dd is not recommended for new users, I would rather have holes in my swapfile than a dead HDD. If a person is worried about holes they can search their system log for **swapon: swapfile has holes**. That is much faster than restoring a system from backup. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq

Comment: @heynnema I am currently using the method I posted here, I have checked it a half dozen times with 18.04 and 20.04 before posting. I have even added a hibernate button using gnome extensions. You are welcome to try it yourself, only takes ten minutes. `resume_offset` is necessary with a swapfile.

Comment: @heynnema: Proof of concept for hibernating with swapfile added.

Comment: Thank You so much. It worked. I've been looking for a way to Hibernate Ubuntu for a really long time.

Answer (score 1):

With only 4G RAM, I'd recommend a 4G swap.

Do this to enlarge your current 2G swap...

**Note**: Incorrect use of the `dd` command can cause data loss. Suggest copy/paste.

```
sudo swapoff -a           # turn off swap
sudo rm -i /swapfile      # remove old /swapfile

sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1M count=4096

sudo chmod 600 /swapfile  # set proper file protections
sudo mkswap /swapfile     # init /swapfile
sudo swapon /swapfile     # turn on swap
free -h                   # confirm 4G RAM and 4G swap
reboot                    # reboot and verify operation
```

Also, do `sysctl vm.swappiness`, and if it returns anything but "60", let me know, and I'll give you further instructions.

Comment: Do you really want to turn a new user, with a rep of 1, loose with dd?

Comment: @C.S.Cameron Hence, the warning **note**, and the **suggestion** to use copy/paste.

Comment: Not sure whether or not to add this comment. Your warning is nice, but after using Ubuntu for fourteen years and seeing similar warnings dozens of times, I managed to accidentally zero my laptop's SSD using dd just last year.

Comment: What can possibly happen if i don't enlarge the swapfile size?

Comment: @wrchunks With only 4G RAM, and too small a swap file, you may run out of RAM, and find your system freezing frequently. This would occur when you have a number of tabs open in Firefox/Chrome, or have many applications running at the same time.

Comment: @C.S.Cameron I hear your comment, and your concern. I'll trust that the OP can copy/paste the commands successfully.

Comment: @wrchunks I you find your system freezing frequently run the "free" command in terminal to confirm you are out of memory, If so, add more swap.