# takes very long time to boot up ubuntu 20.04

Tags: boot, 20.04

I upgraded Ubuntu from 18.04 to 20.04. I am experiencing very slow boot up times. It takes about 2+ minutes to fully boot up.

I have tried to find the solution but couldn't find it.

Log from `systemd-analyze`

```
Startup finished in 10.845s (kernel) + 1min 42.843s (userspace) = 1min 53.688s 
graphical.target reached after 1min 42.647s in userspace
```

log from `systemd-analyze blame`

```
53.567s plymouth-quit-wait.service
41.950s mysql.service                                        
30.942s systemd-journal-flush.service                        
18.520s udisks2.service                                      
16.008s snapd.service                                        
14.604s NetworkManager-wait-online.service                   
13.868s networkd-dispatcher.service                          
12.827s accounts-daemon.service                              
12.276s dev-sda5.device                                      
10.716s polkit.service                                       
10.382s NetworkManager.service                               
10.382s avahi-daemon.service                                 
10.378s bluetooth.service                                    
10.058s switcheroo-control.service                           
10.051s wpa_supplicant.service                               
10.045s thermald.service                                     
10.037s systemd-logind.service                               
 9.005s dev-loop3.device                                     
 8.541s ModemManager.service                                 
 7.917s dev-loop16.device                                    
 7.326s dev-loop10.device                                    
 7.284s dev-loop15.device                                    
 7.084s grub-common.service                                  
 6.983s teamviewerd.service                                  
 6.983s dev-loop12.device                                    
 6.906s dev-loop4.device                                     
 6.906s dev-loop14.device                                    
 6.906s dev-loop0.device                                     
 6.905s dev-loop5.device                                     
 6.831s dev-loop9.device                                     
 6.812s dev-loop7.device                                     
 6.630s apport.service                                       
 6.450s dev-loop13.device                                    
 6.392s dev-loop11.device                                    
 6.153s e2scrub_reap.service                                 
 6.150s grub-initrd-fallback.service                         
 5.294s apport-autoreport.service                            
 4.968s dev-loop2.device                                     
 4.886s dev-loop8.device                                     
 4.603s gpu-manager.service                                  
 4.465s secureboot-db.service                                
 3.973s dev-loop1.device                                     
 3.876s dev-loop6.device                                     
 3.572s rsyslog.service
```

Log from `journalctl -b -u udisks2 -u mysql`

```
-- Logs begin at Tue 2019-05-28 06:03:37 IST, end at Sat 2020-10-10 10:59:44 IS>
Oct 10 09:57:02 asus systemd[1]: Starting Disk Manager...
Oct 10 09:57:07 asus udisksd[777]: udisks daemon version 2.8.4 starting
Oct 10 09:57:13 asus systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server...
Oct 10 09:57:16 asus udisksd[777]: failed to load module mdraid: libbd_mdraid.s>
Oct 10 09:57:16 asus udisksd[777]: Failed to load the 'mdraid' libblockdev plug>
Oct 10 09:57:21 asus udisksd[777]: Acquired the name org.freedesktop.UDisks2 on>
Oct 10 09:57:21 asus systemd[1]: Started Disk Manager.
Oct 10 09:57:54 asus systemd[1]: Started MySQL Community Server.
```

**System Specs** (Dual boot)
OS Name: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (installed in HDD)
OS Type: 64-bit
Gnome Version: 3.36.3
Windowing System: X11
RAM memory: 7.6Gb
Processor: Intel® Core™ i5-8265U CPU @ 1.60GHz × 8
Graphics: Mesa Intel® UHD Graphics 620 (WHL GT2)
Disk Capacity: 1.0TB (HDD)
Windows is installed in SSD and it takes less than 5 sec to boot up.

[I have attached the output of `systemd-analyze critical-chain`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TIJdc.png)

Comment: So MySQL takes 41 seconds to start - I don't know if this is normal or not.

Comment: Have you tried `systemd-analyze critical-chain`?  In the output, the time after the `+` sign is the time it actually takes to start the unit from the time it begins, rather than from the beginning of boot.

Comment: Possibly helpful - https://www.tecmint.com/systemd-analyze-monitor-linux-bootup-performance/

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the slow booting as follows:

1. Run:

   ```
   cd .. cd ..
   cd etc
   sudo gedit fstab
   ```
2. Add a line for your swap partition only IF there is a swap partition:

   ```bsh
   # swap was on /dev/sda? during installation
   UUID=?????????????? none            swap    sw              0       0
   ```

   To obtain the info (`?` and `??????????????`) use the Disks application.
3. Copy `sda?` and UUID, paste them into `fstab` and save it.
4. Reboot.

Hope this works for you too.

Answer (score 0):

### Windows Fast Startup

"When you click “Shut Down” on your Windows 10 PC, Windows doesn't fully shut down. It hibernates the kernel, saving its state so it can boot faster"

For Ubuntu the closest thing is to hit **Suspend** or to enable **Hibernate**.

[Swap area for ubuntu installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1248097/swap-area-for-ubuntu-installation/1248148#1248148)

Comment: giving command `swapon --show` 

NAME      TYPE SIZE  USED PRIO
/swapfile    file     2G    18.2M   -2

Should I enlarge my swap area?

Comment: Swap area should be at least the size of RAM..

Comment: if i enlarge my swap area, will my all data be erased?

Comment: @Hritik Kumar No data will be erased, except perhaps what is in your swap area. That is only temporary anyway and will be rebuilt as soon as swap is turned back on..

Answer (score 0):

Check if all to be mounted partitions specified by UUID in the **/etc/fstab** file do exist. I experienced that after new installations or updates the UUID can be modified on the disk but not in all configuration files. It's the reason for delay.
Show UUIDs using **blkid** cmd  and compare them with those listed in fstab. It could be necessary to use **sudo blkid** to see UUIDs of all partitions - also swap partition.