# Is there any disadvantage of using swap file instead of partition?

Tags: boot, partitioning, swap, hibernate

I'm planning on setting up my new ThinkPad and this time I wanted to plan everything right from the beginning. My notebook has 32 GB of RAM and I want it to be able to hibernate. After doing some research on the internet I found various articles about the right swap size (which should be 1.5 * 32GB in my case, but I guess 40GB should be enough, because I won't run out of RAM). Then I came to the point where I have to decide if I want to use a swap partition or a swap file. I looked at a [website explaining swap](https://www.linux.com/news/all-about-linux-swap-space/) and one which has [hibernation into swap file](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Power_management/Suspend_and_hibernate#Hibernation) described.

So while doing some research on the difference I came to the conclusion, that for Ubuntu 20.04 there should be no disadvantages of using a swap file instead of partition? Is that right, or are there any scenarios where it would be better to have a swap partition (e.g. encryption, security etc...)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is one that has been discussed many many many times.  It really is going to boil down to a matter of opinion.  Some like the fixed partition and others like the ability to remove and create a new one as needed.  Both support encryption, etc.  With the speed of SSDs fragmentation that can happen to the swapfile could be a thing of the past.

Comment: Yes, with a /swapfile and hibernation, you have to add `resume=UUID=XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX resume_offset=XXXXX` to /etc/default/grub. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/1248097/swap-area-for-ubuntu-installation/1248148#1248148

Comment: @Terrance There is a difference. See my comment, and the link.

Comment: @heynnema but this is only a configurational difference right? It works the same for all situations?

Comment: As long as you created your /swapfile using `dd` (not `fallocate`), and made the mods to /etc/default/grub and did `sudo update-grub`, then theoretically it should be the same. Personally, I'd use a swap partition, rather than creating such a huge /swapfile. I'm not 100% sure that your formula of 1.5*RAM is accurate.

Comment: @heynnema Thanks! I guess I will research the correct amount of swap but that's not really topic of this question. But the two of you helped me out a lot. I will just post what you said as an answer, so I can mark this question as answered

Comment: @heynnema I had to add the RESUME to the `/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume` file and I use a swap partition.  But, the RESUME isn't anything that fancy as it doesn't need any `resume_offset`.  Then again, it all boils down to preference.  I don't care for the swapfile and others love it.

Comment: @Terrance The resume_offset is only required if you're using a /swapfile. See the link in my earlier comment.

Comment: @heynnema Again, it is all a matter of opinion or preference.  My original comment wasn't about discussing the differences in how they are setup, it was about how they basically anymore serve the same function.

Comment: @Terrance No problem. I wasn't trying to sway anybody one way or the other. I agree with you... they basically serve the same function.

Answer (score 2):

As @Terrance and @heynnema said in my questions comments it makes no difference if you use swap partition or swap file. It should act the same way.
The only difference is that you have to configure it in a different way, see [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1248331/1033811).